# Attempt at own class and package fails

Tags: errors, packages

I am sorry if the title isn't the best, I could not think of a better one.

I am still new to LaTeX and TeX and I wanted to create a re-usable class and some re-usable packages.

My first package is supposed to be a table that alternates in color. I use the package tabularx for this among other things. I am planning to put this all in a package to create an environment that makes the actual documents look cleaner, but I cant seem to get it working in Overleaf and I really dont know what I am doing wrong. I've tried figuring it out for 2 days, but no luck.

Here is my main tex file (.tex):

```
\documentclass{unisummaries}

\title{Uni Summaries Template}
\author{kevin }
\date{December 2019}

\begin{document}

\begin{alternatingTable}{hh}
    \categories \textbf{\textit{Category One}} & \textbf{\textit{Category Two}}

    \row \textbf{Option 1}& Lorem ipsum.
    \row \textbf{Option 2}& Lorem ipsum.

\end{alternatingTable}

\end{document}
```

I've recently tried to lowercase my class since I wasnt sure if "uniSummaries" is allowed.

Here is my class file (.cls):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{unisummaries}[2019/12/20 Designed to write summaries for the Uni]

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{alternatingtable}

\endinput
```

And here is my package file (.sty)

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{alternatingtable}[2094/12/20 Provides a table that alternates in color between each row]

\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{placeins}
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\definecolor{TableRowColor}{rgb}{0.65,0.85,1}
\newcolumntype{h}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{d}{>{\hsize=.3\hsize}X}

\newenvironment{alternatingTable}[1]
{
    \bgroup
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}%
    \begin{table}[!ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{100%}{#1}
            \newcommand{\headers}[1]{##1 \\ \hline \hline}
            \rowcolors{1}{TableRowColor}{white}
            \newcommand{\row}[1]{##1 \\ \hline}
}
{ 
            \hline  
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \egroup
}

\endinput
```

Any help is deeply appreciated so I can figure out how I can make my own classes and packages to provide common functionality to all my documents. Thank you so much. PS: My programming skills didnt help! :'D

Comment: Weilcome to TeX SX! What is the first argument of `tabularx`  – `100%` – supposed to mean?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should aim to get your package commands to compile in the preamble of a tex document.  That way, you can eliminate that the problem is with your class or package file.

Comment: The (initial)  issues are nothing to do with class or package writing, you should first work out the right syntax for your table by coding a tabularx within the document. Your tabularx preamble of `hh`  is wrong, it should be `XX` see the `tabularex` documentation on changing `\hsize`.   Also you should not have a `table` environment here so delete `\begin{table}[!ht]` (`!` means ignore the settings from the class file, so is a very odd thing to have _in_ a class file)

Comment: @Bernard The 100% was added by me after \textwidth did not work

Comment: @Teepeemm I am afraid I did not quite understand what you mean. :S

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is actually copied from a working document. I've used this exact structure before, it just stopped working inside the package. The "hh" is defined by me using \newcolumntype -> which then refers to X. I will test if this works without the table environment right away though, thank you!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It does work without the table but then the table has a margin on the left and right and does not fill out the whole page. I also noticed it loses any margins on the bottom or top, so the text touches the \hline. Any suggestions there?

Comment: @Kevin there are too many questions here to really be answered in the format of this site. with `100%}{#1}` you will just get errors and no usable  output at all. I can see that you have defined `h` but as I say, the usage is wrong. `h` halves \hsize` so you can not just have `h` as you need to make the total be 2\hsize  fro a 2 column table.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Replacing hh with XX and 100%(% is a symbol for comments, my bad) with \hsize or \textwidth just results in a ! File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body. runaway argument. So I am not sure how to fix that.

Comment: you might be best to delete this question and then ask a new one with a simpler example asking about tabularx syntax. You can't in general nest tabularx in another newenvironment definition  but you can in some cases if you use `\tabularx` and `\endtabular` see the tabularx package documentation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much for all your help, I've added an answer with your input now :)

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to extend a special thank you to **@DavidCarlisle** for his help in the comments.

I've figured out how to solve this issue now. At the bottom I'll post the final solution of everything in case someone is interested (and because I figure I should give something back after such great help!).

Let us break down my many mistakes.

First, I used the `%` character, which in LaTeX signifies that the rest of the line should not be interpreted.

Next, I used tabularx in a new environment, which could not work because tabularx is actually not an environment, but a wrapper and has conflicts with environments so that the end of the environment can never be truly found.

Instead, one must use the commands `\tabularx` and `\endtabularx` thanks again **@DavidCarlisle**.

I also combined table with tabularx in order to get some formatting done that is not necessary at all. So the whole table environment can be entirely removed.

I also defined my own column types that did not conform to tabularx its requirements and thus were removed. Even worse, I used the `!` in the table columns, overwriting anything the class defines, making the re-use of the package harder.

On top of it all, I had renamed the command `\categories` to `\headers` which is now changed.

The final product looks like this once everything is fixed:

alternatingtable.sty:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{alternatingtable}[2094/12/20 Provides a table that alternates in color between each row]

\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\definecolor{TableRowColor}{rgb}{0.65,0.85,1}

\newenvironment{alternatingTable}[1]
{
\newcommand{\headers}[1]
{
\hiderowcolors
##1 \\
\showrowcolors
\hline
\hline
}
\newcommand{\row}[1]
{
##1 \\ 
\hline
}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\noindent
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}%
\rowcolors{1}{TableRowColor}{white}
\tabularx{\textwidth}{#1}
}
{ 
    \hline  
\endtabularx
\egroup
\vspace{0.3cm}
}

\endinput
```

unisummaries.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{unisummaries}[2019/12/20 Designed to write summaries for the Uni]

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{alternatingtable}

\endinput
```

And I also messed up the usages because I did not put the parameters to the commands I was using in curly braces.

Here the new tex file:

```
\documentclass{unisummaries}

\title{Uni Summaries Template}
\author{kevin }
\date{December 2019}

\begin{document}

\begin{alternatingTable}{XX}
    \headers{\textbf{\textit{Category One}} & \textbf{\textit{Category Two}}}

    \row{\textbf{Option 1} & Lorem ipsum.}
    \row{\textbf{Option 2} & Lorem ipsum.}
    \row{\textbf{Option 3} & Lorem ipsum.}

\end{alternatingTable}

\end{document}
```

The output being a beautiful table:

[image: Description of final image]

Final note: I also had to add a workaround for the xcolor package(which I mistakenly did not import properly). You have to sadly hide the colors for the first row and display it afterwards(see `\headers` command).

Now I just wish I could figure out how I can make the coloring start from the first, instead of the second row.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I noticed a weird workaround for the coloring. Depending on whether you have an odd number or even number of rows. If you have an odd number, you need to add an extra "X" to the tabularx definition e.g. `\tabularx{\hsize}{XXX}` despite not actually having a third column. For even number of rows this is not necessary.